# Why won't "fg" reopen emacs after C-z?

Tags: ubuntu

I open a terminal and type `fg` like it says but it says no current process.

I also tried %emacs and got the same.

I'm on trusty tahr 14.04, anyone else got this?
*edit: I was following the built-in tutorial.

Comment: That may not be enough information to answer the question. How did you start emacs? Is it running as a terminal application or as a gui application with a proper os window (you didn't say what OS you're using, but it wouldn't matter; in this case `C-z` will iconify or minimize the window as appropriate for the OS).

Comment: Works for me. Are you sure everything is working correctly? Does this work in `bash` and `emacs -Q`?

Comment: Try `pkill -CONT emacs` but as others have said there is not enough information to answer.

Comment: Are you running `fg` in the same terminal you started emacs in?

Comment: **Did you start Emacs in the background, to begin with?** If not then it's no wonder that `fg` won't move it to the foreground. Try starting Emacs using `emacs &` instead of just `emacs`, if you haven't tried that already. As others have indicated, your question is quite poor - no specific description, no recipe to reproduce the problem. Don't make people guess what you did and what you're asking. Otherwise, you likely won't get good help, and the question might be closed as unclear.

Answer (score 3):

The **fg** job control command should work if you run from the **same** terminal where you entered Control-z.

To find out what processes are available to be placed in the fore ground use the **jobs** command. If jobs does not list your Emacs process, you're in the wrong shell.